# Beautiful Soup - how to clean extracting data?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My question is really trivial but as a beginner in Python I still cannot find my answer..

I pulling some data from web using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

teams = ("http://walterfootball.com/fantasycheatsheet/2015/traditional")
page = urllib2.urlopen(teams)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

f = open('output.txt', 'w')

nfl = soup.findAll('li', "player")
lines = [span.get_text(strip=True) for span in nfl]

lines = str(lines)
f.write(lines)
f.close()
```

But output is a pretty mess.

Is there a elegant way to get a result like this?

```
1. Eddie Lacy, RB, Green Bay Packers. Bye: 7 $60
2. LeVeon Bell, RB, Pittsburgh Steelers. Bye: 11 $60
3. Marshawn Lynch, RB, Seattle Seahawks. Bye: 9 $59
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str.join` on the list and `.rstrip("+")` the `+` off:

```
nfl = soup.findAll('li', "player")
lines = ("{}. {}\n".format(ind,span.get_text(strip=True).rstrip("+"))
         for ind, span in enumerate(nfl,1))
print("".join(lines))
```

Which would give you:

```
1. Eddie Lacy, RB, Green Bay Packers. Bye: 7$60
2. LeVeon Bell, RB, Pittsburgh Steelers. Bye: 11$60
3. Marshawn Lynch, RB, Seattle Seahawks. Bye: 9$59
4. Adrian Peterson, RB, Minnesota Vikings. Bye: 5$59
5. Jamaal Charles, RB, Kansas City Chiefs. Bye: 9$54
..................
```

To separate the price we can split or use `re.sub` to add a space before the dollar sign and write each line:

```
import re
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        line = re.sub("(\$\d+)$", r" \1", line, 1)
        f.write(line)
```

Now the output is:

```
1. Eddie Lacy, RB, Green Bay Packers. Bye: 7 $60
2. LeVeon Bell, RB, Pittsburgh Steelers. Bye: 11 $60
3. Marshawn Lynch, RB, Seattle Seahawks. Bye: 9 $59
4. Adrian Peterson, RB, Minnesota Vikings. Bye: 5 $59
5. Jamaal Charles, RB, Kansas City Chiefs. Bye: 9 $54
```

You can do the same with `str.rsplit` splitting once on `$` and rejoining with a space:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        line,p = line.rsplit("$",1)
        f.write("{} ${}".format(line,p))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list `lines` and write each line:

```
for num, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
    f.write('{}. {}\n'.format(num, line))
```

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is used to get `(num, line)` pairs.

BTW, you'd be better to use `with` statement instead of closing the file object manually:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        f.write('{}. {}\n'.format(num, line))
```