# Generate a dataframe from a string

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, data-cleaning

Inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046792/beautiful-soup-how-to-clean-extracting-data) I have been using the following code to clean-up some data that I obtain using Beautiful Soup:

```
nfl = soup.findAll('li', "player")
lines = ("{}. {}\n".format(ind,span.get_text(strip=True).rstrip("+"))
         for ind, span in enumerate(nfl,1))
print("".join(lines))
```

The problem is that the output of this comes in the format of a string and I would like to store each one of it's lines as a different row in a dataframe. I tried introducing the code in a loop but that would not do. The best I could manage was to store the same string n times into my desired dataframe. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
nfl = soup.findAll("li", "player")

all_data = []
for span in nfl:
    all_data.append({"player": span.get_text(strip=True).rstrip("+")})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```